# Revoked certificate email. But App is submitted and provisioning is Active

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode7, ios-provisioning

My first time submitting ios app so bear with me please.

I basically created the certificate and the previsionsing profiles all on IT connect.
When I opened XCODE, I opened Prefrences->accounts. clicked on download profiles.  I remember clicking on reset which made the provisioning profiles inactive on IT connect. I figured I did it by mistake. So I created new provessioning profiles and  I went to xcode and downloaded them.

Then I submitted my app.

Few hours later, I got an email from apple saying "You revoked the certificate" I went to Itunes connect. The certificate is still there ( and has "revoked button" enabled) and the provesioning profiles are active.

So I am in a limbo now. Is it all good and perhaps the email was referencing by resetting! or does the app need to recreated/resubmitted?

Please help